# when run make it shows make ** no target.stop

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I added a prink in /arch/x86/kernel/setup.c and I tried to run make after modifying the file but it shows errors as in the Title.
I have Makefile in that directory and don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have run one of the `make XXXconfig` options. I recommend `make localmodconfig`. Then you can run `make`. Just make sure you run make in the top level linux source directory and not one of the sub directories as those only contain lines such as `obj-o += setup.o ...` and no actual build targets.

Comment: u r right, i should run make in the top level ,thank u so much. And that means every time I modify a single file, I have to compile the whole kernel again?

Comment: @user3451524 You have to run `make` again but it won't recompile the whole kernel. It will use gcc to figure out file dependencies and only rebuild the required files.

Comment: what is "the top level"?

Comment: @MarkPeterson The top level directory is the directory that you either checked out the kernel source to or unzipped it to. The folder that contains the folders arch, mm, drivers, etc....